# Can I declare and open a file in different lines of code, like in this question I need to keep writing once my file is open

Tags: c, file, fopen, file-handling, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int blocksize = 512;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("mention the file name or too many commands\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    FILE *out;
    if (in == NULL)
    {
        printf("could not open the file %s", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    uint8_t buffer[blocksize];

    int count = 0;
    int precount = 1;
    int flag = 1;
    while(fread(buffer, sizeof(uint8_t), 512, in) == blocksize)
    {
        if((buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && ((buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)) || flag == 1)
        {
            if (flag == 0)
            {
            char filename[9];
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", count);
            out = fopen(filename, "w");
            count++;
            flag = 1;
            }
            if(count == precount)
            {
                fwrite(buffer, sizeof(uint8_t), 512, out);
            }
            else
            {
                fclose(out);
                precount++;
                flag = 0;
            }
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

First I am searching for headers then once I find it, I write it in the `out` file.

I want to keep writing until I find the required headers again and then I want to close the existing file and open a new file until I find those headers again.

Now the problem is when I declare the `FILE *out` inside the if statement it becomes if's local variable and if I do this the way the code here I get seg fault.

Comment: You need to declare `FILE *out;` at the same level as `FILE *in;`

Comment: Then how can I reopen the file?

Comment: Same as now (or almost, I didn't check if your logic is 100% correct). Just declare `FILE *out;` right (after/before) `FILE *in;`. The rest stays as it is and it should be OK.

Comment: still got seg fault 

Comment: You should [edit] and add the new version of your code. Also you should use your debugger and check _where exactly_ the segfault happens. Ans also add some error checking, especially check if `fopen` fails and act accordingly

Comment: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/4/recover/ here is the question does my logic seems right?